# Expanding the client management console to get server functionality?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows

This is an assignment I have in college. The description is so vague that I've come here in frustration.

We have an environment of 4 virtual machines. 2 windows 7 Professional clients, 2 windows Server 2008 R2 servers. All 64-bit.

The assignment reads as follows: "Normally, you can't manage your servers using your client operating system. **What** should you install on your client computer to make the consoles to manage server specific tasks available? (I.E.: active directory users and computers module, IIS management, ...)"

I've asked and it's nothing to do with remote desktop. It needs to be something in the Management Console.

I've tried googling for "expand client management console functionality" and things like that, but I'm getting nothing. I don't think I fully understand the question even.

EDIT: solved.

Future reference: Needed to install the [Remote Server Administration Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7887)
Once installed: it's disabled by default. Click start, type "Windows features on or off".

It'll give you an item like that, click it. There, you'll get a list of features. The remote administration tools are off by default. Turn them on. I did not have to restart.

After this is done, MMC showed a lot more snapins: for IIS, Active Directory, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean snapins?  IIS is manged in mmc via the Internet Services Manager snapin, for example.